# Deploying a Web Application from the command line

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, scripting, publish

Im looking to deploy a web application on a build server.

It is a very small web app and so far i have written a nice little console app that checks out from SVN and then calls msbuild on the .sln file.

This of course is not the same as publishing a web app and so far have not found a programatic way of publishing.

So my question is this..

After msbuild has run can i simply delete all .cs and .vb files and then deploy?

or

Should i really try and find a way to publish programatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using a nant build script where you can use the AspNetCompiler task to publish you web app.

[AspNetCompiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164291.aspx)

Or you can use the [ASP.NET Compilation Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229863%28VS.80%29.aspx) from the command line.